# Problem with TikZpicture in combination with LyX "Missing glyphs"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, lyx

Using the following

LyX Preamble:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

Code in LyX:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}     
\begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,
            ymin=0,
            ybar stacked,
            ]                   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the following error message:

```
"Missing glyphs!" Description: Missing Character: There in no (INSERT ANY LETTER)  in font nullfont!
```

I get this error message many times, with different letters instead of the placeholder `(INSERT ANY LETTER)`

If I delete `ybar stacked` from the code, I do not get this problem.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?

I opened my LyX file with a text editor. Here is the entire code:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{tikzpicture}  
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{axis}[
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

            xmin=0,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

            ymin=0,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

            ybar stacked,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

            ]                   
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
end{axis}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
end{tikzpicture} 
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does the error occur even when you're actually plotting something?

Comment: The problem arises when I want to plot a figure. I can actually click on "Show output anyhow" and it displays the plot as expected, but I would like to solve the problem nevertheless since I am afraid that the same problem might show up in the future but then I might not be able to "click it away"

Comment: There are no `\addplot` commands in your code snippet, which is why I asked. But when I add your code to a default document in LyX it works just fine, so I think we need more information. Can you make a minimal example (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/lyx-user-questions-on-tex-stackexchange) and add it to your post? To add a `.lyx` file to a post, open it in a text editor, and copy-paste everything in the file to the post.

Comment: In my actual Lyx code I use the command \addplot but I removed it to minimize the example. I opened my Lyx file with a text editor and copied the code in the orignal post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using LyX 2.2.1, if I use your code I get your same error.

If I put

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
```

in the preamble, I get the pdf correctly.

Comment: This works for me, too. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @user116192 You are welcome! I'm glad that my answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of TikZ needs to remove garbage at some times (e.g. `pt` from conversion of dimens for numeric calculations). It does not do this by catching and ignoring the garbage by argument. Instead the garbage leaks out and is filtered out by setting the current font to `\nullfont` inside the `tikzpicture` environment. Maybe this is a little bit faster, but the side effect is the unhappy warning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Do I understand you correctly that nothing can be done about this issue?

Comment: @user116192 Yes, the warnings need to be ignored. The alternative is checking and fixing the lots of TikZ internals.